# RAID for social network?

Tags: raid, hosting

I read a bit but not sure if i need RAID 1,2,3,4,5,10? I assume it is like a backup? I have a social network running on mysql and php and have no backups currently. It is dedicated hosting with some CDN. So firstly do i need any RAID? If so what type and are there any extra hardware/software/costs with each RAID number? And software / hardware or both?

Comment: Having no backups is the same as saying *"My data have no value"*.

Comment: @jscott - +1 for the comment, and using 'data' as a plural (which it is!)

Comment: I am not sure how to setup backups so was looking into this now. Its complex with social networks which are updated 24-7-365 and i cannot take it offline also.

Comment: Your assumption that raid is like a backup is wrong, wrong, wrong.

Comment: @Mikey  - given what you're asking, I would suggest that you hire a professional. There's no modern database that I can think of that won't allow you to take online backups.

Comment: Ok, professional hire it is! I assume a system admin should be able to handle all these or some other IT profession is needed?

Comment: Yes - systems admin or systems engineer, or "server" instead of "systems", or some might just call themselves "consultant". Good luck.

Comment: Actually - when you're looking for someone, list all of the technologies (server OS, mysql, apache) that are in your product, and find someone who knows them. Job titles in IT aren't remarkably standardized.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your hoster what is configured for you. If you're paying someone else to manage the hardware, get your money's worth.

Also, pay for backups. RAID is not backup.

/Edit - if you were a sysadmin, I'd have a lot more suggestions, but that's not how your phrased the question so I don't think getting into the weeds is relevant or helpful.

Comment: +1 for the important information without extra info which seems wouldn't be helpful here (re the OP apparently not being a sysadmin)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "social network" running on mysql and php AND you have no backups and don't know what version of RAID you might need, then I'm afraid that you've put the cart WAAAAAAAAY before the horse.

My advice is to take a step back and hire a good sysadmin before you take your site live because your site isn't live with actual users right?.

Comment: Not yet, it's in beta hence I am trying to look into these issues before i make it offical.

Comment: I'm gonna be cynical now, and say we've got enough social networks. I bet you won't get more than a few hundred users.  Is it worth it? Probably not.  Can you just use a facebook group? Probably.